# Hibernate @ManyToOne annotation creating only the child referencing existing parent table

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, nhibernate, jpa

I am currently working on a project in which i have to use manytoone relationship. I want to retrieve the parent from an existing table in the DB and map to a new child object. But each time i do this it fails and instead tries to create the parent over again. here are the variable declarations:

```
@Entity @Table (name= "children")
public class Child implements Serializable{
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn (name = "parent_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
private Parent parent;
}
```

each time i create a new child record it tries to create a new parent with the data of an existing parent i pulled from the database leading to the this error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "parents_parent_name_key"
Detail: Key (parent_name)=(Jimmy) already exists.

Batch entry 0 insert into parents(parent_name, id) values ('Jimmy', '13')     was
aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

then if i try to redo this i get a different error:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:
com.house.entity.Parent
```

Thank yiu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it. the problem  was that I used one sequence for the two tables and other tables. Don't do that if you have multiple relationships across your entities and you wish to persist data across them at one instance. when i changed it, it worked fine.